# npm install jhipster package yo does not satisfy

Tags: npm, jhipster, centos7, yo

I m trying to install jhipster. I followed steps on https://jhipster.github.io/installation.html , but last step (npm install -g generator-jhipster) returns me:

```
npm ERR! peerinvalid The package yo does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer generator-jhipster@2.1.1 wants yo@>=1.3.0
```

I have centOS 7 and npm was installed from repository

```
npm -v
1.3.6
```

I already tried update yo, but seems its up to date for this npm.

```
npm update -g yo
```

---

**UPDATE:**

**Fixed by adding new repostory:**

```
curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup | bash -
```

I was able to install higher version of yo

Comment: You can try 'yo --version' to get your Yeoman version -> we don't test older versions, that's why we require you have at least 1.3.0

Comment: yo --version prints that I m using version 1.1.2, but how can I get higher version? Can I force npm to install higher version somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by adding new repostory:

curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup | bash -
I was able to install higher version of yo